SDL2: How to draw without clearing
I'm trying to make a program that draws parametric equations using SDL2, meaning that I want all points generated from the parametric equation to stay on screen. Here is my full code so far:
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define WIDTH 600
#define HEIGHT 600

// parametric equation - this just draws a circle with radius 200 at the center of the screen.
int parametric(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const float t) {
    float x = WIDTH / 2.0 + 200 * SDL_cos(t);
    float y = HEIGHT / 2.0 + 200 * SDL_sin(t);
    return SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, (int)x, (int)y);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // variables

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    float t = 0;

    // init SDL

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 test",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_METAL);

    // init renderer
    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 100, 255, 255);

    t = 0;

    // main loop

    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
            break;
            default: ;
        }

        parametric(renderer, t);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        t += 0.02;
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

However, when I run the code, this happens:

How can I make it so that SDL2 draws without having to clear the renderer every frame?

Works for me on Windows if I replace SDL_WINDOW_METAL with 0. Also works with SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL and SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN.

Instead of directly rendering to the renderer you could render to a texture and redraw that texture. That way it’s cached too.

Firstly, SDL_WINDOW_METAL is for manually using Metal, I think? Since you're not, I'd remove it. Second, even without that, I don't think not clearing the renderer every frame is portable. You should draw to a texture instead (which will be persistent), and draw that to the screen.

I'm using MacOS Sonoma 14.0 on an M2 MacBook pro. Could that be the issue?
